# The inequality relation between the e.m.f. of two cells and the equivalent e.m.f

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electrical-resistance

Consider two cells of e.m.f. $ε_1$ and $ε_2$ with internal resistances $r_1$ and $r_2$ respectively set up parallel to each other in a circuit as shown in the figure:

[image: Image of a circuit with the above description.]

Let the equivalent e.m.f. be $ε_{eq}$

How can it be proven that $ε_1 < ε_{eq} < ε_2$ if it's given that $ε_1 < ε_2$?

Comment: Do you know how to find the Thevenin equivalent of a network?